# Why is my screen dark with a normal circle?

Tags: windows, windows-11

The other day, when waking up my Windows 11 laptop after a midday break, the screen was darker than usual, as if a semitransparent layer was overlaid over the entire screen. This isn't an issue with my monitors. The issue eventually went away on its own, but a few minutes ago it came back, again after waking up. This time, there's a circle that is colored normally. Here's a screenshot of a small portion of my screen.

Note that my monitors are perfectly fine. This is a problem with what's being displayed, as evidenced by the fact that a screen shot is able to capture it.

What's going on, and more importantly, how can I get rid of the overlay? Internet searches aren't revealing anything, possibly because I don't have a clue what search terms to even use.

Comment: Did you check for "suspicious" processes? There are apps like Dimmer that have similar functionality, don't know which one has a circle like that.

Comment: I didn't see any processes that look suspicious. And Dimmer appears to be focused on setting screen brightness. At any rate, it isn't installed on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With me it was PowerToys that created the issue. I've yet to identitfy the app within that is the culprit.

Terminating the PowerToys worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's the "press Ctrl to highlight mouse pointer" feature. It is especially buggy after pressing Ctrl on the lock screen. Feel free to [edit] the answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was indeed the Find My Mouse feature, enabled by default by pressing left Ctrl twice. It produces a screen that looks the same, but doesn't seem to work consistently. I tend to hit the left ctrl key to wake the computer up since traditionally, hitting Ctrl alone has no side effects. I've now disabled that Power Poys feature.

Answer (score 0):

To add some more detail to the above given answer - it's the "Find my mouse" functionality under the mouse utilities section in the power toys.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had come back to my computer, rattled a key (I must have used my CTRL button) before turning on my monitors and unlocked. Screen was dim and it showed the quarter circle top left. Turned out it's (as @hirnkurve above says) the WHERES MY MOUSE POINTER option  got stuck on, double click your CTRL button finds it. So that's it, just double hit your CTRL keyboard key!